# GATLING - Subscribe checks for multiple messages real-time WebSocket

Tags: websocket, gatling, stomp

I'am using Galting 3.2 and in the web socket stress test I use the subcribe method to test the correct read real -time notifications (stress test for In memory broker):

The part of code is:

val answerEventCheck = ws.checkTextMessage("<<RECEIVER Notification received")
.check(regex("^a.*MESSAGE*.*testing.*"))

....
.exec(ws("<<RECEIVER - SUBSCRIBE")
.sendText("["SUBSCRIBE\n"+"X-Authorization"+":"+"${X-Authorization}"+"\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/topic/messages\n\n\u0000"]")
.await(seconds seconds)(answerEventCheck)
...

This 'subscribe execution' exits (unless in a cycle) when the websocket checks the correct single message (regex pattern). How can I count or read exactly the N notifications arrived for the user that I had opened the socket (with the same regex)?
Before the version 3.2 there was a websocket listener but for this version it's not present. It is possible to count the N notifications received.

Any suggest?

Regards.